# While learning SAGA in QGIS, I get error. What is the reason?

Tags: qgis, error, saga

I use QGIS3.0 in linux(ubuntu 16.06 LST). And whenever I try to use saga toolbox, I get some error like image. I select "save to temporary file". What is the reason? please help me.

[image]